# By using Selenium grid 4 running the Script on Specific Node

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I'm new to Selenium Grid 4 and trying to setting up the grid with Node & Hub Mode and run the test.For example, Below is my setup:

Hub: windows
Node A: windows chrome_v103 ip:192.168.1.1
Node B: windows chrome_v103 ip:192.168.1.2
If I run a test case, sometimes it run on Node A, sometimes on Node B;How can I run a test in specific node, For example in node A, Not Node B

running node by specifying node name if its have the same browser

Answer (score 0):

Posting If you haven't found the answer yet -

1. Set custom capabilities `"networkname:applicationName":"nodex", "nodename:applicationName":"appx"` in your node.driver-configuration in grid config toml file

   `[node] override-max-sessions = true max-sessions = 15 selenium-manager = true detect-drivers = false enable-managed-downloads = true grid-url = "yourIp" session-timeout = 1800 [[node.driver-configuration]] max-sessions = 15 display-name = "Chrome" stereotype = '{"browserName": "chrome", "platformName": "WIN10",  "networkname:applicationName":"nodex",  "nodename:applicationName":"appx"}'`

In your code -

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setCapability("networkname:applicationName", "nodex");
options.setCapability("nodename:applicationName", "appx");
options.setBrowserVersion("96");
options.setPlatformName("macOS");
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444"), options);
driver.get("python.org");
driver.quit();
```

}